# I'm getting a nan result on an integral, Python

Tags: python, math, sympy, integral

I am writing a code that is trying to produce the answer to the integral

I have

```
import math
import sympy as sy

def f(x):
    nume = (x**2)
    denom = (((x**2)-4)*((x**2)+9))
    y = nume/denom
    return y

xInit = 0
xFin = math.inf

x = sy.Symbol("x")
print(sy.integrate(f(x), (x, xInit, xFin)))
```

However, when this code is ran I get the result of nan when i am expecting ((3*pi)/26) as the printed results.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps at some point Sympy tries and multiplies infinity with zero. Bad idea, but that would result in NaN. Or it fails integrating past the infinity at x == 2.

Comment: If you do `f(x).integrate(x).limit(x, oo)` then you'll get `3*pi/26`. That's not the value of the integral though because the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin: I did notice that integrating from `0` to `2` gave me `-oo - I*pi/13`; that imaginary part is at least a little bit suspect.

Comment: The antiderivative involves `log(x-2)` which will give a constant imaginary part for `x < 2`. Integrating from e.g. 0 to 1 using the antiderivative means that the constant cancels which is fine. Probably FTOC should be applied as `(F(b) - F(a)).limit(a, 2, '-')` but instead a limit is used separately for `F(a)` and `F(b)`.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I fix this?

In one sense you don't: there's nothing to fix. The function you give is not integrable (it's neither Riemann integrable *nor* Lebesgue integrable) over the interval `(0, ∞)`, even with the concept of improper integrals.

In more detail, the function you're trying to integrate isn't defined at `x=2`; near `2`, it has a `1/x`-type singularity. If a meaningful value for the integral existed, it should be equal to the sum of the integral of `f` from `0` to `2` with the integral of `f` from `2` to `∞`. Both of those can be defined as *improper* integrals, but the first diverges to `-∞` while the second diverges to `+∞`. The sum therefore isn't well-defined, and any real number is as valid an answer as any other. In other words, NaN or an exception is the only reasonable response that SymPy can give here.

However, all is not lost! You *can* technically define a [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for this integral, and SymPy [has support](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.integrals.Integral.principal_value) for computing those principal values. Here's an example:

```
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 25 2022, 07:25:23) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import Integral, oo
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> Integral(x**2 / ((x**2 - 4)*(x**2 + 9)), (x, 0, oo)).principal_value()
3*pi/26
```

If you want independent corroboration, try submitting the same integral to Wolfram Alpha. Here's a [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-4%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B9%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) to my submission. The result is "integral does not converge", but the Cauchy principal value may also be shown. (There appears to be some indeterminism here: the principal value sometimes shows up and sometimes doesn't, for me.)